URI scheme for remote tunnel?
I know that I can use the VScode URI scheme to refer to a remote repository via ssh, using for example:
vscode://vscode-remote/ssh-remote+myhost/home/user/folder/subfolder

where myhost is one defined in ~/.ssh/config for example.
I was searching if a similar scheme is available for remote tunnels, something along the lines of:
vscode://vscode-remote/ssh-tunel+mytunnel/home/user/folder/subfolder

where mytunnel is the name of a tunnel previously set up in the remote machine using code tunnel.
I could not find such an option, and I don't even know who would be responsible for implementing it (to open a feature request for the appropriate team). Should it be part of the vscode-remote extension? The tunnel extension?
